# SELECT with PDO prepared statements within Database check if there are any results

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
<?php
```

//I wanna make a login page

//This my logon.php which it gets data from my login.php and checks if (username,password)given exists in my Database, and if there are, it allows you to continue to view my index.php.

//I wanna do it with PDO prepared statements.

//Here is my connection to Database

```
$db_host="localhost";
$db_username="root";
$db_pass="";
$db_name="admin";

$db=new mysqli("$db_host","$db_username","$db_pass","$db_name");

echo $db->connect_errno;

if($db->connect_errno){
    die("sorry we have some  problems");

}

if($_SERVER ['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

        $username=$_POST['username'];
        $password=$_POST['password'];

        $username=htmlspecialchars($username);
        $password=htmlspecialchars($password);
```

//Here i try to check in my Database if the given username AND password exists
and somehow check if i got any results.if i got 1,2,3...rows that matches the username and password

//this what i wanna do with PDO...please Help!

```
        $pdo->prepare$sql=('SELECT * FROM members WHERE username = :username and password = :password' );
        $pdo->execute(array(':username' => $username, ':password'=>$password));
```

//Here is what i wanna do if i got any results from my database

```
        if($result){
            $num_rows=mysqli_num_rows($result);
            if($num_rows>0){
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['check']="1";
                header ("Location:index.php");
            }
            else{
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['check']=""; 
                header ("Location:index.php");

            }
        }

    }





    ?>
```

Comment: Mix mysqli and pdo in your code. Either use pdo or mysqli.

Comment: why are you using PDO and `mysqli_` functions together? plus, `htmlspecialchars()` does nothing to escape data. Prepared statements takes care of that.

Comment: sorry i am a new! do i have to change my connection to DB and mysqli_num_rows?

Comment: https://php.net/mysqlinfo.api.choosing Use the same API from connection to query. Don't put a wrench inside the engine block. Something's going to break as soon as you turn the key ;-)

Comment: Thanks.Can you tell me how i can check if i got any result ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two lines are a mess:

```
$pdo->prepare$sql=('SELECT * FROM members WHERE username = :username and password = :password' );
$pdo->execute(array(':username' => $username, ':password'=>$password));
```

First off, we don't see that you created a PDO connection. There's a mysqli connection. Choose either PDO or mysqli,  you can't intermix functions from the two libraries.

The PDO `prepare` function/method returns a statement object `PDOStatement`.

The `PDOstatement` object has an `execute` function/method.

```
try {
   $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
   echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
$sql = "select ... ";
$sth=$pdo->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute(...);
```

You may want to look at the examples in the documentation, e.g.

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

If you want to know if the query returns a row or not, you could simply do fetch from it, and test whether it returns FALSE.

```
$row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

And this line:

```
mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

`$result` hasn't be assigned a value. And again, you can't intermix functions from PDO and mysqli. Those are two different interface libraries.

---

Storing passwords in plain text is a really bad idea.

Comment: Thanks for the Help! what do you mean ''Storing passwords in plain text is a really bad idea'' what should i do?

Comment: This is what i done:                                                                                   $sql = 'SELECT * FROM members WHERE username = :username AND password = :password' ;
  $sth=$pdo->prepare($sql);
  $sth->execute(array(':username' => $username, ':password' => $password));                   and i get errors    Notice: Undefined variable: pdo         and     Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in         what is wrong with the code?

Comment: @Chris: The most likely explanation is that you haven't created a PDO connection object. I provided an example of that in my answer above. I failed to set the error mode for the connection... **`$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`**

Comment: $pdo=new PDO ('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$db_name',$db_username,$db_pass);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $e){
 echo "Connection failed";
}    this is my connection still get that Fatal error...

Comment: @Chris: make sure `error_reporting` is enabled. What's with the space between `PDO` and the opening paren? (Is that valid in PHP? I know it's not valid in some other languages.) And variable interpretation doesn't happen inside of single quotes in PHP, does it? I think `$db_name` is a literal in that context. Either use concatenation  `'...db_name=' . $dbname`, *or* use double quotes instead of single quotes. Examples of creating PDO connetions. [http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php)